# Redirect to login page when auth token is expired

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I have a `authenticated_resource` decorator that prevents access to some routes if the user is not logged in.  I'd also like to prevent access if the token's expiration has passed (where `token_dict['token']['token_expires'] = '2015-08-27T07:51:43Z'`).  How do I do this?

```
def authenticated_resource(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        if session.get('authenticated'):
            return function(*args, **kwargs)

        return abort(403) # unauthenticated

    return decorated

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['username'] != 'admin' or request.form['password'] != '1234':
            error = 'Invalid Credentials. Please try again.'
        else:
            username = request.form['username']
            password = request.form['password']      
            token_dict = getToken(username, password)
            token=token_dict["token"]["id"]
            session['authenticated'] = True
            session['auth_token'] = token     
            return redirect(url_for('getstats'))

    return render_template('login.html', error=error)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the expiration date (in string form) in the session as well.  Check it against the current time along with checking if the token exists in the decorator.

```
from datetime import datetime

...
def login():
    ...
            session['token_expires'] = token_dict['token']['token_expires']
    ...

def authenticated_resource(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        if 'auth_token' not in session:
            abort(403)

        now = datetime.utcnow()
        expires = datetime.strptime(session['token_expires'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')

        if expires <= now:
            abort(403)

        return function(*args, **kwargs)

    return decorated
```